# Remove input commas before submitting a cakephp form with jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, cakephp

I'm working on a form with money inputs and with jQuery I added a way to add commas to those inputs as they write:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.nInput').keyup(function(event){

      if(event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40){
          event.preventDefault();
      }
      var $this = $(this);
      var num = $this.val().replace(/,/gi, "").split("").reverse().join("");

      var num2 = RemoveRougeChar(num.replace(/(.{3})/g,"$1,").split("").reverse().join(""));

      $this.val(num2);
  });
});

function RemoveRougeChar(convertString){


    if(convertString.substring(0,1) == ","){

        return convertString.substring(1, convertString.length)            

    }
    return convertString;

}
```

Now the idea is to remove them before submitting the form, I tried this two approaches:

```
$(":button[type='submit']").on('click', function() {
    $('.nInput').each(function() {
        $(this).val().replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
    });
});
```

And

```
$('#form').submit( function(e) {

    var self = this;
    e.preventDefault();

    $('.nInput').each( function() {
        $(this).val().replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
    });

    self.submit();
});
```

This is the error in cakephp: 'Record not found in table "auctions"'

Comment: Can you show the code for your `#form`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't assigned to `val()` :v

```
$('#form').submit( function() {

    $('.nInput').each( function() {

        var newval = $(this).val().replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");

        $(this).val(newval);

    });
});
```